# Bash script outputting "Info:: not found" when the child process dies

Tags: bash

I have this script

```
#!/bin/sh

echo `pwd`

until `sh ./launch_starbound_server.sh`; do
  echo "Server crashed $?" >> Crash.log
done
```

When I run it and kill the process "launch_starbound_server", it output this in the terminal:

```
Killed
monitor.sh: 5: monitor.sh: Info:: not found
```

The Crash.log does contain the text. The strange thing is that the process does get started. And after some times, the whole process seems to crash instead of looping indefinitely.

**edit**

The server that I'm running usually crash at some point and it's hard to say why. But to be more clear, what I'm trying to do is to make a script that will summon the subscript everytime it crashes.

Having the script to run inside the loop and changing the condition whenever the script crashes could be a way to solve the problem though.

**edit2**

I changed the script to this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/sybiam/starbound/starbound/linux64

while true
do
  ./launch_starbound_server.sh
  echo "Server crashed $?" >> Crash.log
  sleep 1
done
```

I believe it should work, the sleep method is to give time to the OS to free the socket before starting a new server instance. The backticks probably where the problem.

Comment: This script has a lot of unnecessary backticks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this command

```
sh ./launch_starbound_server.sh`
```

is being run in a subshell (via backticks). It outputs a string to stdout. Let's say that string is:

```
Info: foo bar baz
```

So you're effectively running:

```
until Info: foo bar baz; do
  …
done
```

That explains the notice. I can't tell you what's actually killing the script – you'd need to put more detail into the question to figure that out.

Comment: As you suggested, it have been produced by the subprocess failing. I rewrote my script without backticks and it should probably work butter this way. I might also rewrite the script in python instead to get more control.